# Minimizing Travelled Distances When Transforming Rectangle

Tags: integration, optimization, linear-transformations

I am attempting to create an animation where a card (rectangular shape) on a 2D plane reacts to mouse movement. When a user hovers over the card, the extreme cases are:

1. If the mouse moves through the center, the card will translate (slide) in the direction of the mouse.
2. If the mouse moves along an edge or corner in a manner consistent with the card's outer circle, it will rotate around its center.

My idea of formulating this in mathematical terms is to ask, which transformation (rotation + translationn) will move a given point $a$ on the card, which originally rests on $p$, over to $q$ such that the integral over all travelled distances is minimized. So the card coordinate system is $[0,w]\times[0,h]$, the cards original position is described via some affine transformation $T_0:\mathbf{R}^2\to\mathbf{R}^2$ with $T_0a=p$ and I'm looking for $T_1$ with $T_1a=q$ and $$\int_{0\le x< w, 0\le y<h}\|T_1(x,y)-T_0(x,y)\|$$ is minimized. Of course $T_0$ can be taken as the identity w.l.o.g. Is this a well-known problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize in advance for not providing a full answer to your question.

Rotation + translation transformations can be written in the form
$$Tv = A_\theta v + b,$$
for some vector $b$ and a rotation matrix
$$A_\theta = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta)\\
-\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}.$$

With $T_0$ being the identity, you are supposing there is a requirement that $Tp = q$. This allows us to write $b$ in terms of $p$, $q$ and $\theta$;
$$b = q - A_\theta p,$$
so that $$Tv = A_\theta(v-p)+q,$$
and so $$\| Tv - v \| = \| A_\theta(v-p) - (v-q) \|.$$

The idea is then to differentiate the expression you wish to minimize with respect to $\theta$ to find the angles $\theta$ which give you your minimum and maximum, then decide which of the two it is potentially by calculating both values.

To make calculations easier, which also means this is unfortunately not an answer to your specific question, let's say that we wish to minimize the distance squared instead. Let $R$ be the rectangle $(-w/2, w/2)\times (-h/2,h/2)$. So we look for $\theta$ which satisfies
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_{v \in R} \| A_\theta(v-p) - (v-q)\|^2 = 0.$$

By Liebnitz integral rule, this is the same as
$$\int_{v \in R} \frac{d}{d\theta} \| A_\theta(v-p) - (v-q)\|^2 = 0.$$

Then using $\frac{d}{dt} \| v(t) \|^2 = 2 v \cdot v',$
$$\int_{v \in R} 2 ( A_\theta(v-p) - (v-q)) \cdot  \frac{d}{d\theta} ( A_\theta(v-p) - (v-q))  = 0.$$

Now $v-q$ is constant with respect to $\theta$, we can take away the 2, and letting
$$A'_\theta = \begin{pmatrix}
-\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\\
-\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)
\end{pmatrix},$$
we have that we wish to find $\theta$ for which
$$\int_{v \in R} ( A_\theta(v-p) - (v-q)) \cdot A'_\theta(v-p) = 0.$$

Now, for all vectors $w$, $A_\theta w \cdot A'_\theta w = 0$, since $A'_\theta w$ is perpendicular to $A_\theta w$. Thus we look for $\theta$ for which
$$\int_{v \in R} (v-q) \cdot A'_\theta(v-p) = 0.$$

We can then split this into
$$\int_{v \in R} v \cdot A'_\theta v - \int_{v \in R} q \cdot A'_\theta v - \int_{v \in R} v \cdot A'_\theta p + \int_{v \in R} q \cdot A'_\theta p= 0.$$

Now, by choosing our rectangle to be centered around the origin, $\int_{v\in R} v$ and $\int_{v\in R} A'_\theta v$ both vanish, so we are left with;
$$\int_{v \in R} v \cdot A'_\theta v + \int_{v \in R} q \cdot A'_\theta p= 0.$$

Now, note that $A'_\theta = A_{\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}}$, so $v \cdot A'_\theta v = \| v\|^2 \cos(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}) = -\|v\|^2 \sin(\theta)$. Also recall $hw$ is the area of the rectangle. So we wish to find $\theta$ for which;
$$\sin(\theta) \int_{v\in R} \|v\|^2 = hw (q \cdot A'_\theta p).$$

If I calculated this last integral correctly, then this should be solving the equation, after taking the common $hw$ factor,
$$\sin(\theta) \frac{1}{12}(h^2+w^2) = -\sin(\theta)(q_xp_x + q_yp_y) + \cos(\theta)(q_yp_x - q_xp_y).$$

Now, just to check that the formula is more or less what you are looking for, here is a [sketch of the card example you mentioned](https://editor.p5js.org/esteban.gomezllata/sketches/gYxmiS69R). Once again, this is minimizing distances squared instead of distances.

Comment: OMG you even implemented it, thank you so much!  I haven't worked through the math yet, but it looks exactly like I imagined!